# Linq Intersect Comma Delimited String with List Containing Strings using Iqueriable

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

`resultList is an IQueriable<foo>` used as a result for a grid that has filtering options. One of these filters is the project filter .

`foo.projects` is a string that is a string formed out of projects delimited with commas 
Example:

```
foo.projects = "project1,project2,project3";
```

filterProjects is a `List<string>`

Filtering is successful using this code, but because I am using ToList(), resultList can no longer be used for pagination purposes as an IQueriable

```
resultList = resultList.Where(x => (x.projects.Split(',').ToList().Intersect(filterProjects).Count() > 0));
```

My question is: can this be done while keeping resultList as an `IQueriable` ( without using `ToList()`) ?

Comment: The answer will probably depend on which provider is hiding behind your opaque `IQueryable<T>`. Are you using Entity Framework? LINQ-to-SQL? Some other data source?

Comment: I'm confused - your query will still return an `IQueryable`, but it is likely that the condition will _not_ be translatable to SQL as-is.  What makes you think you are not getting an `IQueryable` back?

Comment: Plus `ToList` should not be necessary - `Split` will return a `string[]` which implements `IEnumerable<string>`, so you can still call `Intersect` on it.

Comment: You are correct. Still , my query does not work :( 
Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
resultList.Where(x => x.Projects.Split(',').Any(p => filterProjects.Any(fp => fp == p)))
```

**Update**

As pointed out by Mihai Labo, this is not working on LINQ to Entities, because Split() cannot be translated into a store expression.

Assuming that filter names are not contained into each other (see comment) then the solution can be reworked (to work on LINQ to Entities) as

```
resultList.Where(x => filterProjects.Any(fp => x.Projects.Contains(fp)))
```

Comment: Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: If you can make the assumption that filter names are not contained into each other,  for instance "project1" and "project2" are fine, but there should be no "project1" and "project" as different filters, then you don't need Split(), you can just say x.projects (as a string) should contain at least one element in filterProjects. This condition would be reworked as  resultList.Where(x => filterProjects.Any(fp => x.Projects.Contains(fp)))

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. Could you please add it as an answer ?